# Running the same post job after every stage in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Let's say I have the following Jenkins pipeline script:

```
node {
    stage('Job A') {
        build job: 'Job A', propagate: false
    }
    stage('Post job') {
        build job: 'Cleanup', propagate: false
    }
    stage('Job B') {
        build job: 'Job B', propagate: false
    }
    stage('Post job') {
        build job: 'Cleanup', propagate: false
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to have 1 post job that gets executed after every stage job instead of duplicating it? I also want the next job to wait for the post job to finish.

Comment: is it a `scripted` or `declarative` pipeline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am considering that the cleanup steps required after each job is same otherwise you won't be asking the question.

The easy way is to create your own function which builds a given job and does cleanup.

For waiting unless job is complete, you can set `wait` parameter to `true`

if you are using a `scripted pipeline` you can use the following code.

**Scripted Pipeline**

```
node {
    stage('build_job_a'){
        build_and_clean('job_a')
    }
    stage('build_job_b'){
        build_and_clean('job_b')
    }
    stage('build_job_c'){
        build_and_clean('job_c')
    }
}

def build_and_clean(job_name){
    try{
        echo "building a job: ${job_name}"
        build job: ${job_name}, propagate: false, wait: true
        echo "successfully build a job: ${job_name}"
    }catch(e){
        echo "error occurred while building job: ${job_name}"
    }finally{
        echo "Cleaning up"
    }

}
```

Comment: I am using scripted pipeline. Your solution helped.